# Python pandas monthly cumsum() and reset after hitting max (max = 1 in my case)

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to calculate the monthly cumulative sum on a series of numbers (positive and negative values) but without exceeding 1 (reset the cumulative if true).
This is how I calculated the created CI data but I didn't find a way to reset the sum to 1 after each exceedance of 1 and after each month in the same time.
Thanks in advance for any thoughts you may have, and please let me know if I can provide any more information.

```
df['CI'] =(1+df['CI_rate'].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1M')).cumsum())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do `df['CI'] - df['CI'].astype(int)` to deal with the cap at 1.

Comment: Dear Franco, thanks for your answer, to give you a better idea of the problem, the CI rate is a kind of daily variation of the performance of a solar collector (a negative value equals to the loss of performance and a positive value equals to the improvement of performance), the 1 means that the system is working at 100% of its performance (0% losses),

Comment: the goal is to create the CI (performance curve from the CI rate data), so the maximum of the CI is 1 (100%) and the accumulation should be reset when exceeding 1 and then the losses will accumulate again until the next month or after a positive value that can make the CI exceed 1 again.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Maybe you should edit the question so people can help you better. It would also be good if you can give some sample data with the expected output. Regards